# Laravel 7 authentication not persisting

Tags: laravel

I have a custom guard and provider defined in `config/auth.php`:

```
'guards' => [
    // ...

    'interviewers' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'interviewers',
    ],

    // ...
],

'providers' => [
    // ...

    'interviewers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Interviewer::class,
    ],

    // ...
],
```

My `App\Interviewer` model extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`.

My authentication route authenticates correctly:

```
public function login($token)
{
    $interviewer = Interviewer::where('token', $token)
        ->firstOrFail();

    auth('interviewers')->login($interviewer);

    $interviewer->update(['logged_in_at' => now()]);

    // outputs: "in login controller - 1"
    dump('in login controller - ' . auth('interviewers')->check());

    return redirect()->route('interviews.edit');
}
```

However in my route with an `auth` middleware,

```
Route::middleware('auth:interviewers')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/interview/{form?}', 'InterviewController@edit')
        ->name('interviews.edit');
});
```

it's never authenticated and redirects me to the `login` route. Doing some debugging in `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate`:

```
protected function authenticate($request, array $guards)
{
    if (empty($guards)) {
        $guards = [null];
    }

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        // outputs "interviewers middleware - "
        dump($guard . ' middleware - ' . $this->auth->guard($guard)->check());

        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
            return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
        }
    }

    $this->unauthenticated($request, $guards);
}
```

When doing `artisan route:list`, here are my routes:

```
GET|HEAD  | interviews/{token} | interviewers.login | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\InterviewerLoginController@login | web
GET|HEAD  | interview/{form?}  | interviews.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\InterviewController@edit              | web,auth:interviewers
```

I've read that because routes don't have the `web` middleware the authentication won't persist, but as you can see `web` is included by default. I have another custom guard that uses "traditional" username + password. It's working as expected.

My env for session is `SESSION_DRIVER=file`, my other guards are working as expected.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that I have a test for this and it passes:

```
public function test_can_log_in_with_valid_token()
{
    $applicant = Applicant::all()->random();
    $interviewer = factory(Interviewer::class)->make();
    $interviewer->token = Str::random();
    $interviewer = $applicant->interviewers()->save($interviewer);

    $this->get(route('interviewers.login', $interviewer->token))
        ->assertRedirect();

    $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($interviewer, 'interviewers');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical ID10T error on my part. I didn't realize that I had implemented `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` manually on my model before extending the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` class. PHPStorm had stubbed out those methods for me...

Removing those stubbed methods worked.

Answer (score -1):

Hello in you login method use attempts function that is a function that login user I think with persistence. `Auth::attempts([‘email’ => $request->email, ´password’ => $request->password]);`

That will verify if user can be connected or rejected ( it’s the default Authenticator).

Comment: I don't use a username + password in this situation. I send them a token and [manually log them in](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

Comment: In your guard do you have change the timer ? one is by default as 60 minutes and another is a 3 hours ( 18000 second or 10800 second ) Because if you have change this you're guard will respect your timer. So no persistence because the time i think is expired + you have to make name as single name ( without "s"), no with interviewers but interviewer as guard, but as provider you can user interviewers.